# Poetry echos " Skipping virtualenv creation, as specified in config file" when run in Docker

Tags: docker, python-poetry

I have a Dockerised Python set up with

```
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-ansi mypackage
```

Now when I run this using:

```bash
docker run mycontainer
```

I get extra warning message before my application starts:

```
Skipping virtualenv creation, as specified in config file
```

How do I suppress this message?

Comment: Note that usually the recommendation is to use virtual environments always whenever possible, even in Docker containers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass `--quiet` flag to `poetry`

If you are using an entry point shell script you can do:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# Start trade-executor under docker compose
#

poetry --quiet run mypackage "$@"
```

With the following in `Dockerfile`

```
ENTRYPOINT ["scripts/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Or you can change the command in `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD ["poetry",  "--quiet", "run", "mypackage"]
```

Comment: Thanks very useful to avoid cluttering my FastAPI logs